# Which CMS for photo-blog website?

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I need to add photo-blog to a site that I'm recently working on. It is very simple site so the blog doesn't have to be very sophisticated.

What I need is:

- a CMS that allows me to create simple blog-like news with one (or more) images at the beginning and some description/comment below. Preferably, I would like to create something that works like sites like these two:
  http://www.photoblog.com/dreamie or http://www.photoblog.pl/mending/
- it must be customizable. I want to integrate it's look as much as possible with current page: http://saviorforest.tk
- preferably, it should provide some mechanizm for uploading and storing images at the server.

I thought about wordpress, but it seems to be a little bit too complicated for such simple task. Do you know any simple and easy in use CMS that would work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tumblr would be perfect for that. It was built to easily handle photos, video, text, etc., it can be highly customized, and it can run directly on your own site.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

(It has had some serious server downtime lately, but hopefully that will be fixed soon.)

Comment: I don't think it's what I'm looking for. Unless there is some kind of php framework that allows to display posts from tumblr in custom page.

Comment: Tumblr does have an API. http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything simpler or more customizable than WordPress. Did you know you can add a gallery to a blog post just with a [gallery] shortcode? If you haven't already, read the WordPress page on [Photoblogs and Galleries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Photoblogs_and_Galleries) and check out a few of the plugins listed there. Also look at the [list of WP plugins tagged with "gallery"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/gallery).

Apologies if you have already looked into WordPress this far. I was just looking for a photoblog earlier last year and found WordPress + a gallery plugin a very easy/customizable solution.